# Charting problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I'm having some problems putting a "company goal" on my column chart. I am doing it as a line graph, but the line needs to extend more left, and more right. I've tried setting the x to before where my column chart starts but that doesn't help, it still doesn't start on y axis and and shifts all my info over. this is what I'm getting:

[image: what I'm getting]

and this is sort of the idea I'm going for :

[image: what I'm going for]

i realize that i probably wont be able to get individual goals on there because it's one point, but if someone has an idea...I'm all ears...other than 3d column chart with company and individual goals behind the first 2 series..already though of that, but its not the look I'm going for.

Code:

```
int x = 0;

Chart1.Series.Add("currmonth");
Chart1.Series["currmonth"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
Chart1.Series["currmonth"].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;
Chart1.Series.Add("prevmonth");
Chart1.Series["prevmonth"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
Chart1.Series["prevmonth"].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;
Chart1.Series.Add("compgoal");
Chart1.Series["compgoal"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0; 
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 5;

DataPoint dp3 = new DataPoint();
dp3.SetValueXY(0, 115);
dp3.BorderWidth = 3;
Chart1.Series["compgoal"].Points.Add(dp3);
DataPoint dp4 = new DataPoint();
dp4.SetValueXY(5, 115);
dp4.BorderWidth = 3;
Chart1.Series["compgoal"].Points.Add(dp4);

while (x < 4)
{
    /*DataPoint dp3 = new DataPoint();
    dp3.YValues = new double[] { Convert.ToDouble(115) };
    dp3.BorderWidth = 3;
    Chart1.Series["compgoal"].Points.Add(dp3);*/
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
    dp.AxisLabel = username[x];
    dp.YValues = new double[] { Convert.ToDouble(average[x]) };
    dp.Label = average[x].ToString() + " || " + count[x];
    dp.LabelForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
    dp.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold);
    Chart1.Series["currmonth"].Points.Add(dp);
    //-----------------------------------
    DataPoint dp2 = new DataPoint();
    dp2.AxisLabel = username2[x];
    //dp.XValue = x;
    dp2.YValues = new double[] { Convert.ToDouble(average2[x]) };
    dp2.Label = average2[x].ToString() + " || " + count2[x];
    dp2.LabelForeColor = Color.Brown;
    dp2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold);
    Chart1.Series["prevmonth"].Points.Add(dp2);

    x++;
}

Chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
Chart1.Titles[0].Text = "Name";
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = ddlMonths.SelectedValue;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "$";
Chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend() { Name = "Legend" });
Chart1.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
Chart1.Series["currmonth"].Name = "Current Month";
Chart1.Series["prevmonth"].Name = "Previous Month";
Chart1.Series["compgoal"].Name = "Company Goal";
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: why not use [fusion charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/)?

Comment: I think there would be more people willing to help if there was any info about _which framework you are using_. There are about 100 different UI frameworks out there and every one of them has at least 4 or 5 different charting frameworks, so how should we know which one you are using?

Comment: this is the namespace i'm calling - 
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;

mostly because this is what the company already has as a standard, not the best, but i'm new to the company so not a lot of creative leeway atm ..so doing the best with what i got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used a stripline...solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by setting an XY value for the datapoint on the line chart series, ie:

```
dp.SetValueXY(xvalue,yvalue);
```

create two of these points, one where x is the minimum value shown on the chart, and one where x is the maximum possible value. The line should then draw as you wish it to.

Comment: i've done this before, but i tried again. No luck. It just smushes the chart together, it does extend the line, but not to the y axis for some odd reason..it also erases all the datapoint labels after the first one

Comment: Hmm, ok. Maybe try setting the minimum and maximum x axis limit, if you haven't already? eg Chart1.ChartAreas[areaindex].AxisX.Minimum = min; and Chart1.ChartAreas[areaindex].AxisX.Maximum = max;

Comment: ahh!! thanks.... sooo close..i was wondering if you could do that setting xmin and mx..but couldnt find it anywhere...that fixes the line, but my axis are screwed up..like..the names underneath the column graph

Comment: You mean the axis titles, or the labels on each datapoint? And what do you mean by screwed up...wrong position, wrong data, something else?

Comment: Sorry, here... i took a screenshot so you could see.
notice that the employee names no longer appear underneath the columns. one shifted completely left, and the other 3 are missing
http://imgur.com/AL6IT

Comment: i amended the code, so you can see what i currently have as well..and thanks for all the help

Comment: I can't see why that's happening from the code you've put in the question...are you sure that's the latest version though? I may be missing it because I'm half asleep, but I can't see the x minimum and maximum on there.

Comment: haha, you are right..forgot to include that in the edit..the code is above outputs the most recent picture i posted

Comment: Tough one, I'm really not sure. Why have you commented `//dp.XValue = x;` out? And equally, on the first datapoint, why have you not got that line there at all? What happens if you put them in?

Comment: i commented it out because when i leave it in, the graph gets all funky, i dont know why..pretty much all of the graphs for dp2 disappear..their labels are still displayed, but the actually column is gone. it also shifts the xaxis over..if you need a screenshot i can take one

Comment: nevermind, someone else helped me using a strip line on another forum.. thanks for all the help!

Comment: Glad to hear you've got it working - Just to help other people in future, it'd be worth you putting an answer to your question here yourself, and marking it as such.